# How are DC fast (rapid) chargers able to charge different chemistries?

Tags: battery-charging, dc, automotive

As far as I know different chemistry batteries require different stages of charging.

How are DC fast chargers able to charge any battery chemistry?

Furthermore, there are the 400V and 800V standard battery voltages, but there can be pretty much any voltage a given car battery might have, how does the charger know at what voltage to charge?

Comment: "How" in what sense? Detecting chemistry? Communicating with a controller? Accommodating some voltage and current range? There are multiple aspects here.

Comment: if we're talking car batteries, then the processor in the charger and the battery have a nice little chat, and swap parameters. Only then does the charger fling multiple kilowatts into the battery terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The car and charger talk together via wires separate from the high voltage ones. Here's an example with CHAdeMO:

[image]

([source with lots more info](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319162700_Rapid_EV_Chargers_Implementation_of_a_Charger))

The charger is a voltage-limited DC current source (CC-CV), and the car tells it how much current it needs to output and what maximum voltage it should output.

As a current source, it doesn't set its own output voltage: the output voltage of a current source is always set by the load which takes the current. In this case, the battery sets the voltage.

However the charger has various safeties including output voltage limits, which are set to values sent by the car. If voltage goes out of bounds the charger will react appropriately, for example by lowering current or just stopping the charge.